# SPEmailEventReciever - is this avaliable in sandbox solutions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I was wondering if you could write an sandbox solution using the SPEmailEventReciever class. In the SharePoint SDK documentation it says that the SPEmailEventREciever is not avaliable for use with a sandbox solution, but I found in another piece of document SharePoint that list all class avaliable for sandbox solutions it shows that the SPEmailEventReciever is avalaible for use. Help?

SPEmailEventReciever class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx#2

Microsoft.SharePoint.dll APIs That Are Available from Sandboxed Solutions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537860.aspx#BKMK_AvailClasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not unfortunately, again according to MSDN documentation!

[Screen capture MSDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBX9A.png)

Even tried - it doesn't get accessible

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought, but the second link tells me that the class is accepted for sandbox solutions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537860.aspx#BKMK_AvailClasses

Comment: ..but is also states that several members might be unavailable and you should check, also because certain members in this assembly behave differently than members in other assemblies of sharepoint